# How to represent spaces in MigraDoc

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

For a project i was working on i was required to produce a PDF of whats displayed on screen using Migradoc. I encountered an issue where preceding spaces where getting removed from the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get around this i had to convert the spaces to use the following tag

```
&#160;
```

Answer (score 1):

That question was answered one week ago:
[MigraDoc: How do I add preceding spaces to a String?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19300219/162529)

The way to enter non-breaking spaces depends on the programming language and the editor in use.